# Variable indefinida, pero ya está definida

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema con el siguiente código, por que al momento de tratar de imprimir el  Correo Electrónico me dice que la variable no está definida. Agradecería mucho su apoyo

```
<h1>DATOS DEL USUARIO: <?php echo $_POST["Usuario"] ?></h1>

<?php
$ID = $_POST["ID"];
$Usuario = $_POST["Usuario"];
//$Conexion = require_once '../DBconect.php';
$Conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sistemaescolar");
$Búsqueda = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID=$ID AND Usuario=$Usuario";
$datos=mysqli_query($Conexion,$Búsqueda);
if ($datos == true) {
    while($row=$datos->fetch_array()){
        $ID = $row["ID"];
        $CorreoElectrónico = $row["Correo"];
        $Usuario = $row["Usuario"];
        $Cargo = $row["Cargo"];
        $FechaRegistro = $row["Fecha de registro"];
        $HoraRegistro = $row["Hora de registro"];
    }
}
?>

<div class="Datos">
    <p><b>ID de usuario:</b><?php echo $ID ?></p>
    <br>
    <p><b>Correo Electrónico del Usuario:</b><?php echo $CorreoElectrónico ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: La variable solo esta definida si la kectura de la base de datos devuelve algun valor, si no no la define. Te pasará lo mismco con las otras como $cargo o $FechaRegistro. Cambia if datos == true por datos !=false, porque datos devolverá un objeto con los resultados.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla.

Comment: En la consulta el usuario va entrecomillado: `AND Usuario='$Usuario'"`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está mal estructurado.

Si lo analizas bien, estás definiendo `$ID` y `$CorreoElectrónico` dentro de un `if`, pero si el código no entra en ese `if` (como está ocurriendo de hecho) las variables no estarán definidas, porque el código no pasó por ahí.

Lo lógico aquí sería mostrar poner el bloque `<div class="Datos">` dentro del `if` y agregar un `else` para mostrar un mensaje de que no hay datos, por fallo de la consulta o por otro motivo.

Yo veo otras cosas en tu código:

- Estás mezclando estilos de `mysqli`, lo cual es lícito, pero no recomendable. Usa en todo el estilo orientado a objetos. Es más claro, menos verboso y varias funciones del estilo procedural que usas en la conexión por ejemplo, están obsoletas.
- Usas unos nombres de variable eeeenormes, lo cual será infumable en un programa largo. Te recomendaría también que evites el uso de acentos, `ñ` y caracteres especiales en la nominación, lo cual podría romper el código en ciertos contextos. Para evitar todo esto se suele optar por una convención de nombre en inglés.
- Deberías evitar también nombres de columnas con espacios en blanco, como `Fecha de registro`, esto puede ser problemático, es mejor algo como `Fecha_de_registro`, y si optas por una convención de nombre en inglés, es mucho más breve algo como `date_in`. En el mismo sentido, considera que las bases de datos tienen tipos de datos `DateTime` que servirían para guardar fechas y hora, puede que con un campo de este tipo puedas guardar tanto la fecha como la hora del registro, evitando así una columna adicional y ganando en espacio en la base de datos y en muchas más cosas que verás más adelante cuando avances en programación.
- ¿Para qué es el `require` que está comentado en tu código?.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, tu código podría quedar así:

```
<?php   
    $id = !empty($_POST["ID"]) ? $_POST["ID"] : NULL;
    $user = !empty($_POST["Usuario"]) ? $_POST["Usuario"] : NULL;
    if ($id && $user) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sistemaescolar");
        if ($mysqli) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID=$id AND Usuario='$user' LIMIT 1";
            if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
                #Parece que se espera una sola fila
                #por tanto, no hace falta while
                $row=$datos->fetch_assoc();
                $outPut="<h1>DATOS DEL USUARIO: $user</h1>";
                $outPut.="<div class=\"Datos\">";
                $outPut.="ID: $row[ID] <br />";
                $outPut.="Correo: $row[Correo] <br />";
                $outPut.="Usuario: $row[Usuario] <br />";
                $outPut.="Cargo: $row[Cargo] <br />";
                $outPut.="Fecha: $row[Fecha de registro] <br />";
                $outPut.="Hora: $row[Hora de registro]";
                $outPut.="</div>";
            } else {
                $outPut="Error: De consulta SQL";
            }
        } else {
            $outPut="Error: De conexión";
        }
    } else {
        $outPut="Error: No se postearon los datos";
    }
    echo $outPut;   
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí y si me funcionó. Gracias de antemano